# Can you update the master table from the sub-detail table without having the master table collapse?

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-grid, kendo-grid

Can you update the master table from the sub-detail table without having the master table collapse?

I am running this bit of code:

```
update: {
   url: "/engine.php?q=updateProjectDetails",
   dataType: "json",
   complete: function(e){
     var parentRow = $('tr').closest(".k-detail-row").prev();
     var grid = parentRow.closest("[data-role='grid']").data("kendoGrid");
     var parentDataItem = grid.dataItem(parentRow);
     parentDataItem.set("tscore", JSON.parse(e.responseText).d[0].tscore);
   }
}
```

When it runs the set from the child table, the master table collapses all its child elements for just 1 column update in the master table(datasource).

Is there a way around this behavior, basically, leaving the expanded tables alone and just update that 1 field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that is is not that easy:

1. When you do `set` it updates the master grid causing a refresh and then all rows are collapsed.
2. Expanding the row (using `expandRow`) after `set` is not trivial: using `parentRow` for invoking `grid.expandRow(parentRow);` doesn't work because the when it refreshes the master the HTML seems to change and then is no longer valid.

So what *seems* to work is saving the `uid` of the row and the using it for finding again the `parentRow` and expanding it. Something like:

```
click: function (e) {
    var parentRow = $(e.target).closest(".k-detail-row").prev();
    //find parent grid
    var grid = parentRow.closest("[data-role='grid']").data("kendoGrid");
    //get the parent grid row DataItem
    var parentDataItem = grid.dataItem(parentRow);
    var uid = parentDataItem.uid;
    parentDataItem.set("FirstName", "OnaBai");
    grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + uid + "']"));
}
```

But this does not prevent the inner grid from being re-loaded...